# 'for' loop seems to be looping though twice

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that performs simple input/output operations on a text file in C. It's suppose to display several options to the user then perform the selected operation and re-display said options. The issue I'm having is the for loop I'm using seems to be looping though twice and so options are displayed are twice. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong any help would be appreciated.

*Here's the code:*

```
for (;;) {
    printf("\nPlease choose from the fellowing options: \n\n");
    printf("Press (S) to sreach for a word\n");
    printf("Press (L) to display specified number of text lines to the screen\n");
    printf("Press (A) to append new content to the file\n");
    printf("Press (Q) to quit\n\n");
    printf("Please enter option: ");
    option = getchar();

    if (option == 'S' || option == 's') {
        //Search for a word in file.
        printf("Test\n");           
    }
    else if (option == 'L' || option == 'l') {
        //Display number of line specified by user.
        printf("Test\n");           
    }
    else if (option == 'A' || option == 'a') {
        //Append new content into file.
        printf("Test\n");           
    }
    else if (option == 'Q' || option == 'q') {
        //Quit program.
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
    }       
}
```

*Here's the output:*

Please choose from the fellowing options:

Press (S) to sreach for a word
Press (L) to display specified number of text lines to the screen
Press (A) to append new content to the file
Press (Q) to quit

Please enter option: s
Test

Please choose from the fellowing options:

Press (S) to sreach for a word
Press (L) to display specified number of text lines to the screen
Press (A) to append new content to the file
Press (Q) to quit

Please enter option: Invalid input!

Please choose from the fellowing options:

Press (S) to sreach for a word
Press (L) to display specified number of text lines to the screen
Press (A) to append new content to the file
Press (Q) to quit

Please enter option:

Comment: `printf("Invalid input '%c'!\n", option);` in the last `else` and you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ill guess that the problem is that getchar() read only 1 character from stdin(where you put input into console)
so its dont read the endline(enter) that you insert into the input stream in the first loop and thats why when you call getchar on the second time you get Invalid input.

use sometime like scanf instead or even better read the line into
char* buffer and work on the buffer instead of working with stdin directly.